# Turret Logic like in Contra - XNA

Tags: xna

I'm creating a project which is to remake Contra (NES) using XNA. My problem is I don't have an idea on the logic of turret especially on the part when the turret is rotating with 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, etc. degrees. I'm thinking about getting the position of the player, then calculating the angle from the center of the turret but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Open-ended "How to" questions are difficult to answer, and tend to generate long follow-up discussions. To improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, [edit] your question to provide greater focus on the specific problem you're facing. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To find angle between two vectors:

```
return Math.Atan2(b.Y - a.Y,b.X - a.X);
```